# Return a number of rows in a SELECT UNION of a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that returns a large number of rows. I want to limit the number of rows to 50. How can I do that in a `UNION SELECT` query in a SQL Server database?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_photos]
    (@IDuser NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        photoFileName 
    FROM 
        photos 
    WHERE 
        IDuser = @IDuser

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        photoFileName 
    FROM 
        photos2 
    WHERE 
        IDuser = @IDuser 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be MS SQL Server, so you can use TOP syntax:

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM
 (
   SELECT photoFileName FROM photos WHERE IDuser = @IDuser
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT photoFileName FROM photos2 WHERE IDuser = @IDuser
 ) dt
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there way to order the union result as well by the IDuser (ORDER BY IDuser DESC)???

Comment: Simply add `ORDER BY IDuser DESC` after `) dt`